# How to install Qt 5.6.1-1 via homebrew?

Tags: macos, qt5, homebrew

When you run `brew install qt5` you'll get the latest version (right now that's 5.7.0). A week ago or so, when I ran this command version 5.6.1-1 was installed.

Now I need to install this 5.6.1-1 version again on another machine. How can I do this via brew? (trying to avoid the long compile time)

A `brew search qt5` doesn't show this previous release:

```
$ brew search qt5

pyqt5                                                      qt5 ✔
homebrew/versions/qt52                                     homebrew/versions/qt55
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `qt5` formula resides [here, in Github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Aliases/qt5) and by backtracking to a previous commit you can find a previous version of the formula. The 5.6.1-1 version can be found [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/fdfc724dd532345f5c6cdf47dc43e99654e6a5fd/Formula/qt5.rb).

So to install Qt 5.6.1-1 with Homebrew you can do this:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/fdfc724dd532345f5c6cdf47dc43e99654e6a5fd/Formula/qt5.rb
brew install ./qt5.rb
```

Comment: If you have following error during installation of Qt 5:
  `Error: qt5: Unsupported special dependency :mysql`,
then edit `qt5.rb` file and delete line number `69`:

  `  depends_on :mysql => :optional`

Answer (score 0):

brew install qt@5
From the other versions section of https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/qt